# How do I install Ubuntu from my trial USB stick, preserving all my applications and settings?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 on my PC.  I've been working with it on my USB stick for a few weeks now, and have been loading programs and customizing my settings.  I'd rather not have to start configuring my desktop Ubuntu from scratch.  How do I copy over my OS as-is, with all my programs and all my settings?  Is that possible, or do I have to start from scratch?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can take a backup with "aptik" and restore them later on maybe, I think it's impossible to do.

Comment: You may try using Clonezilla for that purpose.

Comment: Don't see why not. You'll need to free some space on my PC, and create my ext4 partition, then copy everything over from my USB stick, and finaly, reinstall my grub boot loader. All that provided there is a real installation on my USB, and not a live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your software and settings, and install Ubuntu normally using your USB...

You can use Aptik for you backup:

`Aptik` - all you need is a backup directory, stored locally or in the cloud. `Aptik` will backup PPAs, downloaded packages, software selections, application settings and themes and icons. *Very* useful.

You can install it through the ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository –y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

[image]

Did *that* help you? **=)**